# wordpress - Updating older pages and posts via admin panel not working

Tags: wordpress

I created few websites last year using wordpress and I am a fan on wordpress since then. But now, I am facing weird issue with my sites. I want to edit my older pages and posts (older then 1 year) via admin panel, I goto edit page and do changes and click on "update" button, but my changes are not reflecting.

Quick Edit is working, but edit page is not working, so there is no way for me to change the content. Moreover, if I create new page/post then I can edit. But can not edit my older entries.

What can be issue? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Is it saving your changes? Or you're not seeing the updates? Or is it not allowing you to edit the pages at all.

Comment: it is not saving my cahnges. I update my content, and then click on "update" button.. page is refreshed but my content is not updated. It is still old content.

Comment: Have you upgraded to the most recent version of WordPress?

Comment: Do you have a cache plugin installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, found the issue : I had mb_internal_encoding plugin installed on the server. When re-installed everything I tested it.

Thanks everyone for your valuable comments/answers. Happy Wordpressing :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps . May be this will help you:

- Disabling Google Gears if you have that running/installed.
- Deactivating all plugins to see if this resolves the problem. If this works, re-activate the plugins one by one until you find the problematic plugin(s).
- Switching to the default theme to rule out any theme-related problems.
- Renaming the plugins folder via FTP
- Reading http://wordpress.org/support/topic/279132